# git remove untrack files but there's no untracked files

Tags: git, github

I'm not sure how I broke `git`, I trying to do `git pull upstream target-branch`

I got error of

`The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge`

but when I do `git status` I don't see any untrack files.

Answer (score 0):

`git status` shows you only non-ignored files, but you probably have ignored files in addition. See `git ls-files -o` for a list.